# making background inactive when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i click a user name on twitter background it becomes inactive and dark.just like that:

[image: background is inactive]

I want to make my website's background inactive when a button is pressed, how can i do that?

**Note**: and i want to now which solution should i use make a box appear/disappear middle of my site when a button is pressed?i am doig something like this.

```
//in css
.visible{
    display: inline;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

//in jquery
$("#div1").click(function() {
    $('#div2').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
}
```

Comment: Use CSS... Using `:active`

Comment: what you are looking at is a [modal window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). twitter has this awesome api called [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) that makes this easy to do. you could also use css to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a lightbox.
First hit should make you happy: https://www.google.nl/search?q=lightbox

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to build lightbox. Just show fullscreen div with semi-transparent background color for this.

Simple solution:

CSS:

```
.lightbox {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:10;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Show lightbox</a>
<div class="lightbox"></div>
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
$("a").on("click",function(){
$(".lightbox").css({'width':$(document).width()+'px','height':$(document).height()+'px'});
$(".lightbox").show();
return false;

});
```

Comment: now i got your solution man but why we didn't write just "document". or is there a just one word which doesnt use width and height properties for spread itself to the page?